# Cannot retrieve information from API (Beginner programmer)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I would like to start by saying that I am not a developer and this is my very first time writing a code to this extend of complication (at least to me). Any help/guidance would be much appreciated.

The idea of this program is to retrieve the employee user ID (or signature) from an API URL once the name has been entered.

1. I created a folder called WebAPI which will access the API and retrieve the needed information. (please see the code)

   ```
   namespace TimeSheets_Try_11.Controllers
    {
        class WebAPI
        {
            public string Getsignature(string name)
            {


                var cookies = FullWebBrowserCookie.GetCookieInternal(new Uri(StaticStrings.UrlIora), false);
                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                wc.Headers.Add("Cookie:" + cookies);
                wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                string uri = "";


                uri = StaticStrings.UrlIora + name;
                var response = wc.DownloadString(uri);
                Employeename status = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employeename>(response);



                string signature = status.Signature;
                return signature;



            }
        }
    }
   ```
2. I also created a class called Employeename which I defined the variables (please see code)

   ```
    namespace TimeSheet_Try11_Models
    {
        public class Employeename
        {
            public string Signature { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string FullName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
        }
    }
   ```

Problem: There are no visible errors, however, when I start debugging and enter a name in the forms application, I get the error of "System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.'" for the line "var response = wc.DownloadString(uri);" in the WebAPI folder.

Comment: The API may not support TLS 1.2 or may require TLS 1.2. Many server discontinued TLS 1.0/1.1 in June.  How old is the API?  Did  you check for latest?  Your c# code may be defaulting to either TLS 1.0 or TLS 1.1 and you need to specify TLS 1.2.  Try adding : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: Maybe you can try to add `wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;`

Comment: Thank you all so much. I am no longer getting the same error, however, I am getting a new error stating that "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'TimeSheet_Try11_Models.Employeename' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly."